# Preg_replace exact strings only

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "recruitment offer human resource IT for before of";
$string = str_replace(array('it', 'for', 'of'), '-', $string);
```

I want to remove some unnecessary words from the string (in this example - I want to replace `it`, `for`, and `of` with `-`) but I don't want others words to be affected (the above example will also affect the words `recuITment`, `OFfer` and `beFORe`

Result : `recruitment offer human resource - - before -`

Note : I need a solution that does not limit only to these words / string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace()` with `\b`, the word boundary assertion:

```
$string = preg_replace( '#\b(it|for|of)\b#i', '-', $string);
```

Comment: How would you achieve this if "it", "for" and "of" were actually variables?  I have a  situation where I want to run this: `$text = preg_replace( '#\b(logo.png)\b#i', $newLogoName, $text);` but `logo.png` is actually a variable. The following syntax does not work for me: `$text = preg_replace( '#\b('.$origLogoName.')\b#i', $newLogoName, $text);`

Comment: @jmchauv i have tested my solution and it works with your example. You can check it here: https://3v4l.org/NSCmO

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use lookarounds instead of word boundaries. Because  `\b(it|for|of)\b` would match `it` in `:it:` string. I think this is not you want.

```
$string = preg_replace( '#(?<=\s|^)(?:it|for|of)(?=\s|$)#i', '-', $string);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU5wJ8/1)